# What is the meaning of "Independent Oversight"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm reading privacy documents and this words came up, I have no idea what it exactly means.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, i got the meaning the words separately, i just can't understand what it really means together. could you give me an example?

Comment: It means that some independent person or organisation has (or should have) oversight of some (or all) aspects of whatever you are reading about. Given the lack of context, that's all that can be said, I think.

Comment: @Roi Try to find a sentence using the term. That will make it easier to explain.

Comment: An oversight can be a mistake—e.g., I forgot to pay my parking ticket. It was an oversight.  This is not the meaning you are looking for.

Comment: Can you include the whole sentence? It would be easier for us to tell "meaning in context" when we have the context part

Comment: Could you give us the quote from the privacy documents that contains this phrase. I'd rather have that as oversight has more than one meaning.

Comment: @Smock
i've added a screenshot of the document

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza I've added screenshot

Comment: @Xanne I've added screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Independent oversight" means that the activities are done under the principle of segregation of duties and by parties that do not have any reporting line to key stakeholders of the data or the outcome of the data analysis, to avoid the so-called "conflict of interest".

This is why you have consulting or auditing companies providing you with data and audit reports, or overseeing the process, to avoid deliberate tinkering with the data / sampling procedures.

In the manufacturing industries, this is why Quality Control and Quality Assurance should never report to Operations. In the stock market, this is why companies like PwC, KPMG, EY and Deloitte are contracted to provide yearly assessments of a company's finances.